# Regular expression email with specific domain and password with specific condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

- Only allow use email with domain : @company-inc.com
- Password must be 8-20 chars, at least 1 digit and 1 letter

Here what I tried, I found them around the net and kind of build them up (putting different found regex parts together) so I am sot sure they are 100% correct although I tested them and looked like they worked), btw I am using asp.net C# - RegularExpressionValidator control

- for email: ValidationExpression="(\W|^)[\w.+-]*@company-inc.com(\W|$)"
- for password: ValidationExpression='^.*(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d).*$'

1 error I found is that: the email regex allow user enter only domain which is: @company-inc.com (no char before @)

Please verify and explain for me how they work?

Comment: Why can't you test them yourself?

Comment: @MattBurland I tested few cases but not sure 100% that they are correct, chance are there may be a case it will fail, I already found 1 in email regex, it allow user to type only domain (no char before the "at")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the email problem, because I can't find out what is the best regular expression, I have to do 2 steps:

-Let say you want to validate textbox **txtEmail**:

1. Use built-in asp.net **regularexpressionvalidator** with **validationexpression** set for email, it is `\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*` by the way.
2. At your button click event, use string EndsWith function check if `txtEmail.Text.ToLower().EndsWith("your email domain")` is true

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check your regexp : http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/regex-tester/

You can ask questions about how to solve technical problems, but you should test your cody yourself if it behaves the way you want

Comment: Right, that exactly what I did, Asp.net RegularExpressionValidator validate on client side so right after you typed in it show you result, but I need someone explain what I need to put to the regex because you can never test all cases. BTW how to sole the problem with email that I listed on question?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html . In case you didn't, there you can read how regex works. If you had read, you would know what are you doing and what you are not doing. if you know what is missing, then add it. Regards